# How do you build the matrix for finite difference 2D Laplace equation on variable mesh?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-differences

Can someone explain how to build the matrix equation using finite difference on a variable mesh to solve the 2D Laplace equation using Dirichlet conditions?

Given the 2D equation
$$\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial y^2}=0$$

I understand how you can use a central finite difference scheme on a variable mesh to obtain [this equation](https://mathformeremortals.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/a-numerical-second-derivative-from-three-points/):

$$\frac{2A_{i+1,\;j}}{(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})}-\frac{2A_{i,\;j}}{(x_{i+1}-x_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})}+\frac{2A_{i-1,\;j}}{(x_{i+1}-x_{i})(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})}+\frac{2A_{i,\;j+1}}{(y_i-y_{i-1})(y_{i+1}-y_{i-1})}-\frac{2A_{i,\;j}}{(y_{i+1}-y_{i})(y_{i}-y_{i-1})}+\frac{2A_{i,\;j-1}}{(y_{i+1}-y_{i})(y_{i+1}-y_{i-1})}=0.$$

However, I am at a complete loss as to how to code this up into a matrix form which can be solved like $\mathbf{Fa}=\mathbf{b}$. My question here is, how do I build the $\mathbf{F}$ matrix given the above equation? Furthermore, what if the number of cells in the x- and y-domain are not equal (e.g. suppose in the x-domain we have N = 50 cells and in y-domain we have M = 40 cells)?

The mesh is a rectilinear but with variable grid cell sizes. Some cells are larger than others. It is a product grid (i.e. could be produced using a `meshgrid` command in MATLAB).

I could probably do it using a ton of `for` loops, but there must be a better and more efficient way. I have also found some sources which discuss the problem when using a uniform mesh but I am not sure how to generalize that to a non-uniform mesh.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am coding in MATLAB.

Comment: We usually prefer the *central* second difference for the Laplace equation discretization.  Why does "forward difference" come into the picture?

Comment: Could you not still reorder the grid into a single vector, and then build the block matrix F (assuming Neumann or Dirichlet BC's) using the kronecker product as is done with a uniform grid?

Comment: @hardmath I am using central difference. Sorry for the confusion. I removed the word "forward" from the question.

Comment: @garserdt216 Yea I understand the part about re-ordering into a single vector.. But the "building the block matrix F using kronecker product" is the part I am missing. Maybe you can elaborate on that in an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You mention having a "variable mesh" or "a non-uniform mesh", but this is not specific enough to understand what kind of mesh you have.  Perhaps even though the mesh is not "uniform", it is nonetheless a "product grid" kind of mesh?  You say (for example) "what if the number of cells in the x- and y-domain are not equal?"  This is not a big obstacle.  Keep in mind that some of the "unknowns" $A_{i,j}$ may be known from Dirichlet boundary conditions (but you've said nothing about this).

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for reply. I've updated the answer for clarity. It is a product grid and using Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: There are some alternatives in [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_885.htm).